# how to get data from json?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have controller

```
var subCategories = m_listsRepository.GetSubCategories(id);
var items = subCategories.Select(x=>new MyDataNameAndId(){Id = x.Value, Name = x.Text});
return Json(items);
```

And ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlString,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: districtId }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
            $.each(data, function (key, MyDataNameAndId) {
                alert(key);//== 0
                alert(MyDataNameAndId);// then throws
                $('select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId').append('<option value="0">Select One</option>');

                $.each(MyDataNameAndId, function (index, manager) {
                    $('select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId').append(
                            '<option value="' + manager.Id + '">'
                            + manager.Name +
                            '</option>');
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Controller is worked.
alert("success"); - is show
alert(key); - is show 0
alert(MyDataNameAndId); - not show.
I need generate in 'select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId' options from select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId

How do this? this understand?

I do not know how to show what passed json

**json string:**

```
[{"Id":"53","Name":"футбол"}]
```

Comment: Duh, you can at least tell us what's not working.

Comment: Is there a problem? If yes, what is it? Please explain your issue and do not just post some code and let us figure out the rest. In any case, how to access properties and array elements of a specific data structure is too localized IMO. Have a look at the structure of `data`, learn how to access object properties and you are sorted.

Comment: Could you post an example of the JSON received? Also what do you get if you console.log data in the success callback?

Comment: Could you post what the JSON result looks like? I.e. go to the urlString yourself. Thing to note: If you're using e.g. Firefox w. Firebug or Chrome you can put breakpoints and debug what data becomes.

Comment: To show what the JSON result is just do console.log(data); as data is supposed to the the JSON object returned. If the first key is 0 then it is an array, so unless we see depeer into the JSON it will be hard to know if you are grabbing things properly.

Comment: data[0].Id, data[0].Name should access your data right. So MyDataNameAndId.Id and MyDataNameAndId.Name in your first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JSON output you've written out, I'd rewrite it a little bit like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlString,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: districtId }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data) return; // if data is empty, return

        var $select = $('select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId');
          // put the select element in a variable so you don't need to
          // jquery select it again

        $select.append('<option value="0">Select One</option>');
          // I guess you first want to add a "select one" option

        // data should be an array e.g. [{"Id":"53","Name":"футбол"}]
        $.each(data, function (key, manager) {
           // for each "manager" in the "data" array

           // manager should be an object in the data
           // array e.g. {"Id":"53","Name":"футбол"}
           // no need to for each it

           $select.append(
                    '<option value="' + manager.Id + '">'
                    + manager.Name +
                    '</option>');
             // add the manager in the select box
        });
    }
});
```

I'm assuming stuff though. Use a javascript debugger (such as developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox) to check what values you get from the ajax call. Put the breakpoint inside the function and then watch what the data becomes (in this case it should be an array of objects containing Id and Name).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(MyDataNameAndId, function (index, manager) {
                $('select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId').append(
                        '<option value="' + manager.Id + '">'
                        + manager.Name +
                        '</option>');
            });
```

should be just

```
$('select#ChangeOnsubCategoryId').append(
         '<option value="' + MyDataNameAndId.Id + '">'
         + MyDataNameAndId.Name +
         '</option>');
```

The sample code works for me without exceptions which leads me to believe there's something wrong with the JSON being returned. Check that it actually returns the string you posted.